# Removing a key binding

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

How can I remove a (globally set) key binding? My emacs binds `set-mark-command` to `C-@`, `C-SPC`, and `M-SPC` by default, and I want to free `C-SPC` from it without assigning something else within emacs so that I can use that for a keyboard shortcut defined in the OS.

Comment: I don't believe it's needed: if a key shortcut is defined in the OS, the OS should grab it and not send it to Emacs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does `global-unset-key` do the trick?